# Conditionally skipping iterations of a for loop in R

Tags: r

My code is designed to look at protein sequences and count the number of a specific type of "motif" in those sequences. The particular motif I'm looking for is S/T XXX S/T so anything that fits this pattern should be counted as a "hit".

Currently, my code cannot handle the following scenario:

S S S S S S S S S S

The number of hits here should be 2. SSSSS and SSSSS. However, because of the way my code is written, it returns 6.

Is there a way to get my for loop to skip ahead when certain conditions are met? For example, if index "i" and index "i+4" are both S/T, I'd like to skip to index "i+5" and continue running the code.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
  count = 0

  for(i in 1:length(proteinseq)){
    if(proteinseq[i] == "S" && !is.na(proteinseq[i+4]) && proteinseq[i+4] == "S"){
      count = count+1
    }
    if(proteinseq[i] == "S" && !is.na(proteinseq[i+4]) && proteinseq[i+4] == "T"){
      count = count+1
    }
    if(proteinseq[i] == "T" && !is.na(proteinseq[i+4]) && proteinseq[i+4] == "S"){
      count = count+1
    }
    if(proteinseq[i] == "T" && !is.na(proteinseq[i+4]) && proteinseq[i+4] == "T"){
      count = count+1
    }
  }
  return(count)
}
```

Put another way, I'm trying to deal with the problem of overlapping or "nested" motifs. Once a hit has been established (and the counter updated), I no longer care about the amino acids at indices i, i+1, i+2, i+3, and i+4. I want to move directly on to i+5 and keep going with the for loop.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, why not use a ready-made package. See [motifmatchr](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/motifmatchr.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This seems to work for now but will definitely check the package out for future reference. Appreciate the input :)

Answer (score 2):

The stringr package from tidyverse has what I think you need, just need some regex too. The `str_locate_all()` function will provide a list of matrices showing the start/end positions of the matches within the target string. I'm simply grabbing that matrix and counting the number of rows, which is the number of matches.

```
library(tidyverse)
nrow(str_locate_all("SSSSSSSSSS", "[ST][A-Z]{3}[ST]")[[1]])
```

To do this over multiple test strings, feed it a character vector:

```
matches <- str_locate_all(proteins, "[ST][A-Z]{3}[ST]"))
count <- unlist(lapply(matches, nrow))
```